# Migrating "bootstrap-touch-slider.js" to joomla

Tags: joomla, slider, migration, joomla-module

Hi I am migrating my html bootstrap site to joomla 3. So far things are looking good. I am using the bootstrap touch slider in my html version which works fine and I am stuck how to move it to Joomla. Is there any way to do this or do I need to use/buy a slider module extension?THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is to create your own module and embed slider js in, otherwise you can try to modify the present one. In both cases if you have never done one before you is suit buy the extension you found.

Comment: Thanks for that Bruno!! ;)